# Regular expression that matches a single word in any order

Tags: javascript, php, regex

After a long, unsuccessful search I am starting to wonder if what I am looking for is possible, I would like a regular expression which requires that each letter chosen is mandatory but only once and in any order.

Example : `^[abc]{3}$`

The result I expect would be that it matches only that :

```
abc, bac, cba, acb
```

While I get :

```
acc, abb, cca, aab
```

Do you see where I am going with this?

Comment: Incorrect dupe because OP wants each letter to be mandatory in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a regex like this with a negative lookahead of the matched character in a back-reference:

```sh
^(?:([abc])(?!.*\1)){3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1v9i2F/4)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way.

```
^(?!.*([abc]).*\1)[abc]{3}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NlIekf/1)

The *negative lookahead*

```
(?!.*([abc]).*\1)
```

asserts that no character is repeated and

```
[abc]{3}
```

together with the two anchors asserts that the string has a length of three and is composed of the characters in the character class.